# How to save additional user data as part of the registration process?

Tags: plugins, widgets, user-registration

I've created a multi-part tabbed registration form that includes about 40-45 custom fields aside from user name, password and email.  The goal is to create a new user registration and store the validated / sanitized contents of the field inputs into a new table in the database.  This table will be used as a registry and searched by public users.

When I call wp_create_user, the only 3 allowable arguments are user name, password and email.  Is there another hook I should call that will post in my other fields?

Here is my form thus far:

```
class qfpregister extends WP_Widget
{
  static private $login_registration_status;
  static function registration_form(){
    $username = esc_attr( $_POST['username']);
    $password = esc_attr( $_POST['password']);
    $firstname = esc_attr( $_POST['firstname']);
    $middlename = esc_attr( $_POST['middlename']);
    $lastname = esc_attr( $_POST['lastname']);
    $companyname = esc_attr($_POST['companyname']);
    $dateofbirth = esc_attr($_POST['dateofbirth']);
    $ssn = esc_attr($_POST['ssn']);
    $workaddress1 = esc_attr($_POST['workaddress1']);
    $workaddress2 = esc_attr($_POST['workaddress2']);
    $workcity = esc_attr($_POST['workcity']);
    $workstate = esc_attr($_POST['workstate']);
    $workzipcode = esc_attr($_POST['workzipcode']);
    $homeaddress1 = esc_attr($_POST['homeaddress1']);
    $homeaddress2 = esc_attr($_POST['homeaddress2']);
    $homecity = esc_attr($_POST['homecity']);
    $homestate = esc_attr($_POST['homestate']);
    $homezipcode = esc_attr($_POST['homezipcode']);
    $phone = esc_attr($_POST['phone']);
    $fax = esc_attr($_POST['fax']);
    $email = esc_attr($_POST['email']);
    $website = esc_attr($_POST['website']);
    $biography = esc_attr($_POST['biography']);
    $photofilename = esc_attr($_POST['photofilename']);
    $billingsameashome = esc_attr($_POST['billingsameashome']);
    $billingsameaswork = esc_attr($_POST['billingsameaswork']);
    $chfcearneddate = esc_attr($_POST['chfcearneddate']);
    $chfccert = esc_attr($_POST['chfccert']);
    $pfsearneddate = esc_attr($_POST['pfsearneddate']);
    $pfscert = esc_attr($_POST['pfscert']);
    $msfsearneddate = esc_attr($_POST['msfsearneddate']);
    $msfscert = esc_attr($_POST['msfscert']);
    $msearneddate = esc_attr($_POST['msearneddate']);
    $mscert = esc_attr($_POST['mscert']);
    $qfpearneddate = esc_attr($_POST['qfpearneddate']);
    $qfpcert = esc_attr($_POST['qfpcert']);
    $othercreds = esc_attr($_POST['othercreds']);
    $regtype = esc_attr($_POST['regtype']);
    $ccnumber = esc_attr($_POST['ccnumber']);
    $ccexpmonth = esc_attr($_POST['ccexpmonth']);
    $ccexpyear = esc_attr($_POST['ccexpyear']);
    $cvvnumber = esc_attr($_POST['cvvnumber']);
    /*
{
    $html =
    '<div>';
        $html .= '<!-- Nav Tabs -->';
        $html .= '<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">';
            $html .= '<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#contactinfo" aria-controls="contactinfo" role="tab"
             data-toggle="tab">Contact Info</a></li>';
            $html .= '<li role="presentation"><a href="#designations" aria-controls="designations" role="tab"
            data-toggle="tab">Underlying Qualifying Designations</a></li>';
            $html .= '<li role="presentation"><a href="#attestation" aria-controls="attestation" role="tab"
             data-toggle="tab">Attestation</a></li>';
        $html .= '</ul>';
    $html .= '</div>';
   $html .= '<div class="tab-content">';
   $html .=  '<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active container-fluid" id="contactinfo">';
        $html .= '<form action = "' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
            $html .= '<div class = "row">';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for = "username">Username <strong>*</strong></label>';
                    $html .= '<input type = "text" name = "username" value = "username">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for = "firstname">First Name <strong>*</strong></label>';
                    $html .= '<input type = "text" name = "firstname" value = "firstname">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for = "middlename">Middle Name </label>';
                    $html .= '<input type = "text" name = "middlename" value = "middlename">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for = "lastname">Last Name <strong>*</strong></label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text" name="lastname" value = "lastname">';
                $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="row">';
                $html = '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for = "passowrd">Password <strong>*</strong></label>';
                    $html .= '<input type = "password" name = "password" value = "password">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for = "companyname">Company Name</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text" name="companyname" value = "companyname">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="dateofbirth">Date of Birth <strong>*</strong></label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="date" name="dateofbirth" value = "dateofbirth">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="ssn">Social Security Number <strong>*</strong></label>';
                    $html .= '<input pattern="{d3}-{d2}-{d4}" name="ssn" value = "ssn">';
                $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="row">';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for = "phone">Phone Number <strong>*</strong></label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text" name="phone" value = "phone">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for = "fax">Fax</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text" name = "fax" value = "fax">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="email">Email <strong>*</strong></label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text" name = "email" value = "email">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="website">Website</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text" name="website" value="website">';
                $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="row">';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label><strong>Business Address</strong></label>';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label><strong>Home Address</strong></label>';
                $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="row">';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="workaddress1">Business Address 1</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text" name="workaddress1" value="workaddress1">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="homeaddress1">Home Address 1</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text" name="homeaddress1" value="homeaddress1">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="bio">Biography / Areas of Specialty</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text"  name="bio" >';
                $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="row">';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="workaddress2">Business Address 2</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text" name="workaddress2" value="workaddress2">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="homeaddress2">Home Address 2</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text" name="homeaddress2" value="homeaddress2">';
                $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="row">';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="workcity">City</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text" name="workcity" value="workcity">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="homecity">City</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text" name="homecity" value="homecity">';
                $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="row">';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="workstate">State</label>';
                    $html .= '<select name="workstate" type="text">';
                        $html .= '<option value="">Select...</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="AL">Alabama</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="AK">Alaska</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="CA">California</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="CO">Colorado</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="CT">Connecticut</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="DE">Delaware</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="FL">Florida</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="GA">Georgia</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="HI">Hawaii</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="ID">Idaho</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="IL">Illinois</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="IN">Indiana</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="IA">Iowa</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="KS">Kansas</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="KY">Kentucky</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="LA">Louisiana</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="ME">Maine</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="MD">Maryland</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="MI">Michigan</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="MN">Minnesota</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="MS">Mississippi</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="MO">Missouri</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="MT">Montana</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="NE">Nebraska</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="NV">Nevada</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="NM">New Mexico</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="NY">New York</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="NC">North Carolina</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="ND">North Dakota</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="OH">Ohio</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="OR">Oregon</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="SC">South Carolina</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="SD">South Dakota</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="TN">Tennessee</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="TX">Texas</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="UT">Utah</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="VA">Virginia</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="VT">Vermont</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="WA">Washington</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="WV">West Virginia</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>';
                        $html .= '<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>';
                    $html .= '</select>';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="homestate">State</label>';
                    $html .= '<select name="homestate" type="text">';
                    $html .= '<option value="">Select...</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="AL">Alabama</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="AK">Alaska</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="CA">California</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="CO">Colorado</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="CT">Connecticut</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="DE">Delaware</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="FL">Florida</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="GA">Georgia</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="HI">Hawaii</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="ID">Idaho</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="IL">Illinois</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="IN">Indiana</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="IA">Iowa</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="KS">Kansas</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="KY">Kentucky</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="LA">Louisiana</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="ME">Maine</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="MD">Maryland</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="MI">Michigan</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="MN">Minnesota</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="MS">Mississippi</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="MO">Missouri</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="MT">Montana</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="NE">Nebraska</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="NV">Nevada</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="NM">New Mexico</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="NY">New York</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="NC">North Carolina</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="ND">North Dakota</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="OH">Ohio</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="OR">Oregon</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="SC">South Carolina</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="SD">South Dakota</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="TN">Tennessee</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="TX">Texas</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="UT">Utah</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="VA">Virginia</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="VT">Vermont</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="WA">Washington</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="WV">West Virginia</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>';
                    $html .= '</select>';
                $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="row">';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for "workzip">Work Zip Code</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text" name="workzip" value="workzip"/>';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="homezip">Home Zip Code</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="text" name="homezip" value="homezip"/>';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="billingsameashome">Billing Address Same as Home Address?</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="billingsameashome" value="billingsameashome"/><br/>';
                    $html .= '<label for="billingsameaswork">Billing Address Same as Work Address?</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="billingsameaswork" value="billingsameaswork"/><br/>';
                $html .= '</div';
                $html .= '<div class="col-md-3">';
                    $html .= '<label for="photologfilename">Photo/Logo Filename</label>';
                    $html .= '<input type="file" name="photologfilename" value="photologofilename"/>';
                    $html .= '<input type="submit" name="contactnext"/>';
                $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>'; // close tabpane

    return $html;
 }
```

}

What function(s) should be called to add the new user and the corresponding data as meta inputs on the user record?

Comment: You can store your additional data as user meta, or if you need to make db queries to insert your fields, you can `add_action('user_register', 'my_insert_callback', 10, 1)` . This passes the new inserted user id to the callback function

Comment: So, it sounds like I need a two-step process.  The first is to register the user and the second is to add all the contents from the registration as additional data fields?  Should the plugin have a separate step for creating the meta fields, or can all this be done when the user is created?

Comment: This can all be done at the same time. In the `my_insert_callback` function you would have access to the newly created user id, like `my_insert_callback($user_id)`. In that function, you will perform your db queries (or meta inserts)

Comment: if you have a code example of how you call create user, that would be helpful in guiding you where to make the additional calls

Comment: Updated with code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function that you're hooking into `user_register`, you need to create the user and save the values. First, I'd recommend using `wp_insert_user()` instead of `wp_create_user()`.

You might do something like this:

```
$userdata = array(
    'user_email'  => $email_address,
    'user_login'  => $user_name,
    // this is automatically salted
    'user_pass'   => 'plain_text_password',
);

// this function returns the user id
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

$data = array(
    'field_key_name' => $data_one,
    'field_key_name_two' => $data_two,
    );

foreach( $data as $k => $v ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, $k, $v );
}

// if wp_insert_user fails, it returns an error object
if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    // error
} else {
    // success
}
```

If you are saving the data to a custom table, you would perform that update query in place of `update_user_meta()`, which saves your data to the `wp_usermeta` table.